# Filtering SQLite records using strftime

Tags: android, sqlite, strftime

I have SQLite database in Android app with records like sample below

```
id           date
1            2023-01-29T15:56:00.733533+01:00
2            2023-01-29T15:56:02.092214+01:00
```

I need to filter these records by days, month, etc. I found that strftime function should the best way to do this, but my SELECT is not working. Can someone please help what I'm doing wrong.

My SELECT is

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE date = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '2023-01-29');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time is stored in ISO-8601 standard format

Do this instead

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)='2023-01-29'

//for a particular month

SELECT * FROM history WHERE strftime('%m', date)='2'
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you can format your timestamps to a specific format and the correct syntax is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) = '2023-01-29';
```

or, for a specific month like '2023-01':

```
SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m', date) = '2023-01';
```

or, for a specific year like '2023':

```
SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE strftime('%Y', date) = '2023';
```